# Delete files from SD

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, sd-card

I was using an SD card with GoPro. On device format didn't work one day, so I tried erasing it in Disk Utils on my Mac (Big Sur 11.2.2). It appears to be blank, but when I re-mount it again - all files are in place. Tried even dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m - no luck, all files are in place after re-mount. Is this SD card is defective?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of disk utility? Make sure to enable `show all devices` under `view`. Generally SD cards hardly ever fail.

Comment: It’s the classic write error firmware lock. It’s dead. SD cards have a remarkable fail-rate.

Comment: Oh wow, don’t know why I believed SD cards were so safe. Just did some research and it turns out they are indeed known to fail often. Sorry for my wrong comment and thanks @Tetsujin for correcting me! I must have been lucky that none of my SD cards have failed....

Comment: @X_841 Yeah, fraid so. I used get through literally thousands of them for work. Never trust one as far as you can spit;) and certainly never as the sole storage location for any data.